# WatchKit Interface : Is it possible to add multiple labels in a tableView group without any of the labels being pushed to the right?

Tags: objective-c, swift, interface, watchkit

This is somewhat hard to explain, but basically I have one label in a tableView group that needs to take up the width of the group and placed at the top. I want to add a second label at the bottom of the group and take up the width of the group as well. However, I cannot do this. When I add my second label it gets pushed to the right automatically. Seems, the second label can't be on the same horizontal plane as the first label. Is there a way to resolve this. I can place my second label at the bottom, but it just gets pushed off to the right and off screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add both labels to the group and then, set in that group vertical Layout (Attached screenshot). Also both labels should have width: relative to container
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the group's settings in Interface Builder, you'll see an option to change the layout type to Vertical, rather than the default Horizontal. That should help you achieve the layout you're looking for, if I understand correctly.